# React: Show Error Modal if uploaded image file is too large

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to show a notification Modal if an image which I want to upload is too large. My problem is, that the `handleUpload` function is an external function. How can I render the modal?

My parent component:

```
const MyParent = () => {
    const boundHandleUpload = React.useCallback(handleUpload);

   return  <UploadInput
                onChange={boundHandleUpload}
                accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif,.jpg,.png,.jpeg,.gif"
            />

}
```

My upload input component

```
interface MyProps
    extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement> {
}

export const UploadInput = ({
    onChange,
}: MyProps) => {
    const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    return <input ref={inputRef as any} onChange={onChange} />
};
```

and my handleUpload function:

```js
export const handleUpload = (evt: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const target = evt.target as HTMLInputElement;
    let file, img;
    if ((file = target.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            if(this.width > 1000) alert("Show Modal");
        };
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
};
```

How could I show a React component Modal instead of the alert?

Comment: The simplest would probably be to use `useState` to have a boolean property like `errorMessage`. Instead of `alert("Show Modal")`, call `setErrorMessage(true)` or `setErrorMessage("Your message")`.

In the component that hosts `handleUpload`, display a component of your chance if `errorMessage` is truthy.

Comment: @sjahan Yes this is the standard way for a modal. But how could I do it with an extern function?

Comment: Ah I got your point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function, even if external, must know about React state if you want it to work with React.

Just wrap your function `handleUpload` inside another function, to save `setShowModal` in the closure.

This way, you can edit the state of your component!

```
export const handleUpload = setShowModal => (evt: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const target = evt.target as HTMLInputElement;
    let file, img;
    if ((file = target.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            if(this.width > 1000) setShowModal(true);
        };
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
};
```

Now, `handleUpload` is a function that returns your event listener, so you just call it by passing `setShowModal` and it will return the same thing than before, but with the access to the state!

```
const MyParent = () => {
   const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
   const boundHandleUpload = React.useCallback(handleUpload(setShowModal));

   return  <>
             <UploadInput
                onChange={boundHandleUpload}
                accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif,.jpg,.png,.jpeg,.gif"
             />
             {showModal && <Modal/>}
           </>

}
```

Hope this is clear, feel free to ask if it is not!

Comment: Thank you! Don't have thought about this way. Very cool :)